# how to show large image if clicking in image in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

jqgrid image column is defined using colmodel below.
In form edit mode if mouse is over image cursor changes to hand but click in image is ignored.

How to show large image in separarate window if clicked in image ?
Large image is retued by url `'http://localhost/Grid/GetImage?id=' + options.rowId` (without size parameter).

```
{"label":"Logo","name":"_image_Logo","edittype":"image",
    "editoptions":{"src":""},
    "editable":true,
    "formatter":function(cell,options,row) {
      return '<img src="http://localhost/Grid/GetImage?size=150&id=' +
               options.rowId +'" />';
} ,
"search":false,"title":false,"width":150},    

{"edittype":"file","label":"","name":"Logo","search":false,
"title":false,"width":150,"hidden":true,
"editrules":{"edithidden":true},"editable":true}
```

**Update**

I tried Oleg and Michael suggestions using colmodel below. I need to pass row id to image controller. In grid clicking image works OK, big image is opened. `options.rowId` returs image id.

In edit form, row id is not passed. How to pass `options.rowId` instead of `e.target.id` in click event ?

```
{"name":"Image",
"edittype":"image",

  "editoptions":{
    "src":"",  
    "dataEvents":[{"type":"click","fn":function(e) {
      window.open('GetImage?id=' + e.target.id, e.target.id )
  }
}]},

  "editable":true,
   "formatter":function(cell,options,row) {
    return '<a href="GetImage?id=' + options.rowId+'"><img src="GetImage?size=54&id=' + 
         options.rowId +'" /></a>';
} 
,"search":false,"title":false,"width":54},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example `onCellSelect` or `beforeSelectRow` to catch `click` on the image and implement any custom action (like to show large image) which you need.

If you need to implement some action on `click` on image only in the editing mode you can use `dataEvents` property of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editoptions).

Comment: I tried click event handler in form editing but failed to pass image id to controller. I updated question.

Comment: @Andrus: You can just get the id of last selected row (using `getGridParam` for `"selrow"`). It will be the id which you need. To be sure that the user not select another row during the form is opened you can save the `"selrow"` inside of `dataInit` or inside of `beforeShowForm` (or `beforeInitData`) and then use the saved value inside of `click` handler.

Comment: @Oleg Can I get value of the column (datafield) in editoptions?

Answer (score 1):

what if you change your formatter return to something like `<a href="LARGE_IMAGE_URL"><img src="IMAGE_URL" /></a>` ? Is this what you want?

Comment: Thank you. Your answer does not work in form editing since form editing generates img tag itselt and does not allowe to wrap it into <a> tag based in my knowledge. How to wrap image in form editing with <a> element ?